# My daughter's US passport is expired but she has a valid French passport. Can she can travel back to the US with her French passport and approved ESTA

Tags: customs-and-immigration, passports, us-citizens, esta, denied-boarding

We are flying to Mexico from Boston on 4/10 and we have just noticed that our 10 year old daughter's US passport is expired. She does have a valid French passport to travel on. I dont expect any issues going in to Mexico, but have concerns for the way back. I have applied for an ESTA indicating her dual citizenship and it got approved, so technically she has the paperwork to board the plane.

But I'm concerned that once the airline sees the rest of the family with either green cards (for me, me husband and our other daughter) or US passport for our son, they might ask why she is traveling on ESTA and deny her boarding if they realize she has an expired US passport....
I'm less concerned about immigration once in the US as we can prove her citizenship by showing the expired passport and they cannot deny her entry...
Is there a big chance that american airlines might deny boarding??

Comment: You correctly identify the issue — no one knows if American will allow her to board the flight back to the US. There's a significant probability that they'll refuse. Read Hilmar's answer [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/98536/i-have-an-expired-us-passport-can-i-enter-us-on-my-foreign-passport-with-esta?rq=1). Given the chaos that'd ensue if she were refused, you should renew her US passport now using an [expedited process](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/passports/get-fast.html).

Comment: How long will you be in Mexico?  If you're planning to stay for a while you might consider getting her a new passport there.  The Boston passport agency is [currently accepting appointments for ”life-or-death emergencies only"](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/passports/get-fast/passport-agencies.html), though depending on your location you might be able to go to Portsmouth NH, Stamford CT, or St Albans VT instead.

Comment: Thanks both. I've tried all the passport agencies nearby and cannot get an appointment but will keep trying. We are staying a week in Mexico, maybe i can call the consulate to see what they suggest

Comment: you could also consider... not flying to Mexico for a week in the middle of a deadly pandemic.

Comment: while @mic 's comment is off-topic, I agree. Is it strictly necessary to travel to a foreign country (or from your point of view, your home country most likely) in time of pandemic?  The numbers are going up, because people are relaxing.  And their is no vaccine for under-16s yet

Comment: @mlc Right, so assuming they've paid, they should just throw it all away? Cute, I'd LOVE to be so rich as to have that luxury

Comment: @Crazydre, this health crisis has been with us for over a year now. Every travel now booked was done knowing that covid can stop that travel.

Comment: Has something changed in the ESTA rules? I thought that dual US Citizens were not allowed to apply for one.

Comment: @MarkJohnson The system's inconsistent and will occasionally grant it to a dual citizen. However, several handling agents I've asked said they check the actual details of the ESTA and will deny boarding in this case (unless a valid US passport is held)

Comment: @Willeke Then again, it's repeatedly seemed to calm down only to get worse again, essentially going in waves. And you say "covid can stop that travel"; well yes, but it doesn't in this case - OP's perfectly able to travel to Mexico with their family as Mexico don't have much in the way of restrictions.

Comment: Not in restrictions, but people should be aware of the risks and Mexico is not safe. The lack of restrictions does not help there.

Answer (score 1):

For the return trip, unless you can get her US passport renwed in time, you cannot enter the US by air. Take a domestic flight to a Mexican border city (e.g. Tijuana) and cross the land border with her expired passport